# How to prove that $n \equiv 1 \mod (m-1)$ implies $a^n \equiv a \mod m$ for all $n, m, a \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider $n=561 = 3\times 11 \times 17$. We note that
$$561 \equiv 1 \mod (3-1), (11-1), (17-1).$$ It's then said that this implies that $$
 a^{561} \equiv a \mod 3, 11, 17 \quad \text{for all}\;a
 $$

I wanted to know how to see that this is always true?

EDIT: Does the result only hold when $m$ is one of the prime factors of $n$?

Comment: Assuming $m$ is prime, try using Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: Further reading on this topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number

Comment: @TeslaDaybreak: Ok, FLT says that $a^{m-1}\equiv 1 \mod m$ (for $m$ prime with $(a, m)=1$), but I can't seem to be able to make the connection with $n \equiv 1 \mod (m-1)$.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Consider, say, $n=m=10$. Then $2^{10}\equiv 4$ and $3^{10}\equiv 9$. So there clearly must be _some_ limitation on what factor of $n$ you choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on using FLT when $m$ is prime: if $(a,m)\neq1$ then $m|a$, so the result is trivially true.

Hence we may assume $(m,a)=1$. By FLT, $a^{m-1}\equiv1\pmod m$. Write $n=k(m-1)+1$, then $a^n=a(a^{m-1})^k\equiv a\cdot1^k=a\pmod m$.

More generally, as Stinking Bishop mentioned in the comments, the argument still works when $m$ is a [Carmichael number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number).

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you! I was beginning to get frustrated with being unable to make the connection.

Comment: @J.Doe No problem! If it resolves the question, please consider accepting the answer.